# Show Home page as Category page

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I'm working on a custom Prestashop theme for my e-commerce, and I want to show the index homepage as the category pages.

I have a one big category (Home) that contains 4 subcategories ( Girl, boy, children, Babies)

I've setup the pages of the categories to show a 4 column list, and i want the same in the homepage ( to show all the products of my prestashop products with pagination, the home category ) but, I tried to copy the code, and of course, it doesn't work right the way....

How can i setup an specific Category ( Home in my case ) for re-use the code from category.tpl ?

Because i think, smarty doesn't see the home page as a category page: so can't use globals $category or $subcategories.

Thanks for your help,

Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

Normally in PS, on homepage the featured products are shown. Featured products are those products which are added in Home Category directly, but it has a limited number of products.

If you want the home page to be as category page, then you have to modify the homefeatured module or copy past that module to create a new module for that home page. Now in that module, copy past the code from the category controller  to fetch products count and fetch products. After assigning it to smarty variables, you can access them in your template file for that module, like in homefeatured.tpl.

For pagination, you have to add the pagination.tpl file in your module template file.

Hope this will give you the idea that how you can do it.

Thank you

Comment: It's a good idea, I'm going to try that and get back to you, thanks.